# How to get first 4 bytes of function signature

Tags: web3js, javascript

I need to get the first 4 bytes of several function signatures, to determine what method I need to use to decode a database of transactions that contain input data.

How can I do this in javascript?

Example:

From this input data `0x5174e8530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c516d5a6d62396238503364624c434c7636377374356d434632347a6a5043515a69664a6f78725854566e4a6d7a332f6d657461646174612e6a736f6e00000000` I want this function signature `0x5174e853`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you have and what you need? You have transaction input data, and you want the function signature from it?

Comment: From this input data `0x5174e8530000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003c516d5a6d62396238503364624c434c7636377374356d434632347a6a5043515a69664a6f78725854566e4a6d7a332f6d657461646174612e6a736f6e00000000` I want this function signature `0x5174e853`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input data is a string, you can simply select the first characters corresponding to the signature like so:

```
let input = "0x5174e8530000000000000000000000000000000000000...";
let signature = input.slice(0, 10);
```

In fact, this is exactly how web3js implements it (see [here](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/blob/9b7540d283c3c72978ebdfacc0dea2d0f3f36a05/packages/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js#L58)).

Comment: Sure, but how do I know `(0, 10)` will always be 4 bytes? I have to do this throughout several hundred thousand transactions.

Comment: The function signature is always 10 characters (including 0x) as far as I know.

Comment: I just checked web3js repo and this is how they do it (see my edit).

Comment: @committer actually this may not be a funciton signature, I can send a transaction with "hello" as data, or any other binary stuff like an image.